# Como remover mensagem do warning obsoleto para $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA?

Tags: php, deprecated

Estamos utilizando `php://input` nas requisições em **AngularJS**:

```
//método
public function putData() {
     $params = file_get_contents("php://input");
     return json_decode($params);
}
```

Como está sendo usado:

```
$postData = $this->putData();
$request = $this->getRequest();
$request->setParam('data',$postData->token);
```

Já tentei:

```
$GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'] = -1;
```

Também no htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_flag always_populate_raw_post_data -1
</IfModule>
```

E no php.ini:

```
always_populate_raw_post_data = -1
```

E nenhum funcionou. Estou usando o **Zendframework 1.12.20**

Para ver os erros, estamos usando **php-console**, o qual acusa vários warnings desse tipo.

Comment: Não há nenhuma possibilidade de substituí-lo pelo `php://input`? Já que é o recomendado.

Comment: Então, ele já faz isso, o problema é que no php 5.6 ele fica dando esse warning.

Comment: No `php.ini` configura a linha `always_populate_raw_post_data = -1`

Comment: @MarcelodeAndrade, eu já fiz isso, inclusive coloquei na descrição da pergunta.

Comment: Você reiniciou seu servidor depois de fazer a alteração em `php.ini` indicada?

Comment: Sim, reiniciei, isso aconteceu em duas máquinas diferentes, mac e windows.